# How to add two sub-text field under one table attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I'm working on my simple rails practice. And i wanna add two text field under one attribute?
eg: from Wikipedia 'Battle of Agincourt' ,Attribute 'Belligerents', there are 'England' VS 'France'

but what i have done is: After i enter 'King of England' & 'kingdom of France'  it shows only one of them 'kingdom of France(or England)'
and here is my code in index:

```
<td><%= battle.Belligerents %><p>VS</p><%= battle.Belligerents %></td>
```

code in _form:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Belligerents %>
    <br />
    <%= f.text_field :Belligerents %> 
    <p>VS</p> 
    <%= f.text_field :Belligerents %>
</div>
```

and code in show:

```
<p>
    <b>Belligerents:</b>
    <%= @battle.Belligerents %>
</p>
```

what should i do, so that the table will show both two different objects?

Comment: More information... what search are you using? Something to reproduce?

Comment: ahhh its annoying that i cant add images,  im just practising. sry dont get what u mean. i just want my table column show both sub-column instead of just showing one of them.

Comment: Why can't you add another column and another text field?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Britain here's the example, just wanna make a similar table like the one on the right side.

Comment: You really should have another column and text field, if you know there will always be 2 countries as part of the battle. Otherwise, consider a join table in the middle between models like Battle and Country. Otherwise, you'll have to take in a string like "England VS France" and verify it's in that format, and then parse it to split it up for your view.